# Recommended process for credit card additions/'edits' to event registrations?

Tags: civievent, registration

Using CiviCRM 4.6.4 and Drupal 7.41, we have a large event set up with complex pricing (3000+ registrants each year, lots of price options). Folks forget to register for things the first time through, or they change their mind.

We haven't been able to determine a good way to process these people who need to edit their fee level choices. I can edit fee level choices just fine when there isn't any money involved, but don't see a good way to make a 'credit card 'edit' to a registration'.

To make it more difficult, we would prefer to turn 'multiple registers with same email' *off*, because we tend to have admin assistants and the like sign up many folks under one email and it takes a lot of staff time to sort that out.

The fee level choices must be accurate and held in a single event record (no dupes for the event) to print the correct badge onsite, so if we do need to submit a second registration we would have to create a new with all fee level choices and delete the old ones. This tends to cause the financial tally to be off and is a different admin headache, but this is the route we have taken for now.

Does anyone have a recommendation for processing these credit card edits without the admin headaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not the only one looking for this solution, but it has been unfunded so far because it would be so complex.

As an alternative, you might consider separate events, either using the [Event Additional Signup extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-additional-signup) or the new conference session features.  People who come back later and want to sign up for an additional option can just sign up for the event directly.

You'd then have a different, but much simpler, customization to build out: just getting the appropriate events onto someone's badge.

Comment: Thanks! I'll explore the additional signup - the badges shouldn't be an issue but some custom reporting may be needed to get at event information as a whole.

Comment: Strongly agreed that customizing how the badges get generated is a much better approach than trying to retroactively mangle a previously created registration. Not to mention, keeping that trail of changes is probably helpful also.

Comment: This will work if we can get the onsite registration contractor to modify their system to deal with it. Not sure if this can happen but I do believe it is the correct way if possible - I was being somewhat myopic about the badge printing before because of this outside company. @AlanDixon useful way to put it thanks.