# Dealing with assistants and schedulers: Can you setup a rule that when emailing someone, their assistant will also get the email?

Tags: civievent, civimail, email, activities, activity

This was [partially discussed before](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/recommended-process-for-credit-card-additions-edits-to-event-registrations?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C14.3992), but it's been so long, I am making a new post.

What is currently happening: Assistant or scheduler for a person registers their boss, using the scheduler or assistant's email, not the boss. Then for whatever reason, the boss will expect emails to go to their email address when we are contacting those that RSVP.

There are many ways to approach this, but the end result we want is that the boss' email is entered when registration takes place and that there is an option to include another email to be CC'd on all communications.

Does a solution like this already exist?

Wordpress and CiviCRM - please no drupal webform answers.